# А есть ли в Qt аналог urlencode из php?

Tags: qt5, c++

А есть ли в Qt аналог urlencode из php, чтобы кодировало QString в url строку заменяя пробелы + и прочим?

Answer (score 0):

```
QByteArray ba = QUrl::toPercentEncoding("{a fishy string?}", "{}", "s");
qDebug(ba.constData());
```